# Slope-Intercept and finding parallel lines

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm reviewing for my test today and I came across this question:
Which of the following lines is parallel to the line through the points $(1,3)$ and $(2,6)$?

Answers:

$a.)\:3x-y=4$

$b.)\:x-3y=4$

$c.)\:y=3$

$d.)\:x=3$

Now I did ${Y_2-Y_1 \over X_2-X_1}=3$. And the correct answer is $a$. My question is how do I use the number $3$ that I got to find out that it is $a$?

Answer (score 1):

Good job, you found that the slope of the line passing through the points $(1,3)$ and $(2,6)$ is $3$.

Now you have to remember that **any line parallel** to this line must have the **same** slope.  So we know that the slope of any line parallel to this line must have slope $3$.

If you remember your slope intercept form, when we write the equation of a line in the form $y = mx + b$, the slope of this line is $m$.

So, look at each of your answer choices, and write them each in slope intercept form.  You should get:

a) $y = 3x - 4$

b) $y = \frac{1}{3} x - \frac{4}{3}$

c) $y = 0x + 3$

d) $x = 3$

The only line in these choices with slope $3$ is choice a).  Choice b) has slope $\frac{1}{3}$, choice c) has slope $0$, and choice d) has no slope (since it is a vertical line!).

So, a) is the line parallel to our line, since it has the same slope as the line passing through $(1,3)$ and $(2,6)$.

Answer (score 0):

Two lines are parallel (in the $xy$ plane) if their slopes are the same.

Consider to lines $y_1$ and $y_2$ such that

$$y_1=mx+c_1,~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ y_2=mx+c_2,$$
for some $c_1$, $c_2$ constants such that $c_1\neq c_2$, none of them $0$.

They are parallel if and only if they are never equal at any point. Suppose they are not parallel, therefore they are equal at some point $x_0$: $mx_0+c_1=mx_0+c_2 \Rightarrow c_1=c_2,\rightarrow\leftarrow$. This is a contradiction, therefore they are parallel.

What you did: $\dfrac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}=3$, means that the slope of the given line is $3$. Therefore you have to look for a line with slope $3$. This is the case of option $a)\; 3x-y=4 \Rightarrow y=3x-4$.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you want to do is remember are the two rules about slopes:

1) Lines are parallel if their slopes are equal.

2) Lines are perpendicular if their slopes are the negative reciprocal.

The points you were given have a slope of, $${Y_2-Y_1\over X_2-X_1}={6-3\over2-1}=3.$$

So we want to find the other lines that also have slope 3.

Don't forget that the equation of a line is $Y=mX+b$ where $m$ is the slope and $b$ is the $Y$-intercept

So the slopes for each of the questions are given below:

$A)\ 3$

$B)\frac 13$

$C)\ 0$

$D) \ \text{undefined}$

The only one with the same slope is $A)$ so the only parallel line is $Y=3x-4$